# how to upload django project (attendancesystem) into centOS server

Tags: mysql, django, web-services, centos

I am just getting my hands on to django and linux server so still newbie. My question is I have a django project which is an attendance system and I would like to upload it to my server and i'm using CentOS6. I would like it so that other user can also use it and log into it. I totally no idea on what to do first and what to be aware off and so on. I am totally lost. Can anyone help me step by step that will help me on archiving this. Please ask if you need more information on anything.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Don't they have documentation?

Comment: What is the hosting service you are using?

Comment: Thks @catherine i am afraid they don't have it. I wanted to know how to do with the django project? do I have to package it or just like copy and paste into server or how??

Comment: thks @arulmr i am using tdchosting.

Comment: If they support Django, they will have documentation for that

Comment: thanks @catherine will double check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, someone has made a **step by step documentation** on how to install Django to a CentOs server:

http://itekblog.com/installing-python-django-on-centos-6-3-is-easy/

Deploying a web application in production is a **critical task**. If you have no knowledge about Linux, you will need assistance from a system administrator to understand **exactly what you are doing**.

Comment: thks @poiuytrez. I have already install django on my server and its running good. Maybe I didn't clarify my question right my mistake. I have done a project using django its an attendancesystem and I wanted to upload it on the server so my other user can also login and make use of the system. But the problem is I don't know how to do it since this is my first time dealing with the server.

Comment: @Rhinodj Is you project under a source control software like git or svn?

Comment: hi @poiuytrez. its in git.

Comment: Great @Rhinodj, just do a git clone on your server to retrieve the source code :). It is the easiest way to deploy your project.

Comment: thks @poiuytrez. how do i do that git clone on my server? can you tell me step by step documentation. I'm sorry i'm stuck again.